# How to call a workflow in Apex?

Tags: apex

I have a requirement, which was initially build using workflows- but due to a change in the need of functionality. I had to move it to trigger & apex.
As part of this feature,earlier the workflow used to send emails. But post moving this to trigger,workflow doesn't fire as DML delete makes the record unavailable for workflow to fire.

Now for this requirement: I want to know,is there a possibility or way that I can call that workflow in the Apex code? I cant find a standard business service from salesforce for that?  Please suggest.

Comment: You can't just call arbitrary rules. You'll have to implement whatever you were doing (e.g. sending an email) purely in Apex Code. This is trivial with a little bit of reading.

Comment: yeah i have used apex code to this but wanted to know if in salesforce do we have an option to call workflow from apex.

Answer (score 3):

Your question suggests you want to fire a workflow on a record that doesnt exist anymore ? If so, I propose it cant be done but do wonder whether you have your process right...

Comment: Guess i got me answer - from apex i cant call a workflow. About process, its  right, thats how the business wants the requirement to be.It wants the record to be deleted the moment certain step is done on a record,but as trigger has precedence over workflow..the workflow doesn't get the record to fire. Though did this using apex mailing feature, I had put this question in here so that i can know if in salesforce we have any option to call workflow from apex